# Configure apache server to pick up the HTML5 base tag href for angularjs one page app

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp, angular-ui-router

I read at least a dozen of posts about it, and found something like to setup in my site's root folder (which is www/pg-dev). htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^weiadesigner/pg-dev
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ http://weiadesigner/pg-dev/$1 [L,R=301]
```

it suppose to (I think), redirect from any attempt to access weiadesigner/pg-dev to http://weiadesigner/pg-dev/$1. However, still nothing happen, I still receive the 404 Not Found issue.

I access the WAMP server through my computer name which is weiadesigner with chrome. /pg-dev is the folder where my site is. I try to tell the Apache to redirect all subdomain access (meaning, if someone access weiadesigner/pg-dev/events in a url bar in a browser) , for example weiadesigner/pg-dev/events, will respond with AngularJS router instead of the 404 Not Found from the Apache server, because I am using the HTML base tag that is setup in the index.php in its  with

```
<base href="/pg-dev/">
  <base target="_blank" href="http://weiadesigner/pg-dev/">
```

I am having a big hard time to find any valid solution on this.

Comment: The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable *only* contains a hostname, `/pg-dev` will never be a part of that variable. Other than that, I have no clue what your problem is.

Comment: @Jon Lin Basically, if I use one page app, the relative url will cause a 404 Not Found if I access it directly without go through first , with the index page, for example, I can get on mysite then click on the link from my site to go to mysite/events, but I can not just type mysite/events directly in the url bar because it wil get me a 404 Not found, because server thinks I am trying to access another site that is url with mysite/events

Comment: So what's wrong with the `<base>` tag? That's the way you're supposed to handle relative URL bases.

Comment: @to prettify the url without use #, that's why I used base